# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' when installing a Python package via a setup.py script

Tags: python, r, installation, coda

I am trying to install the Python package "py_coda" from this github:

https://github.com/surhudm/py-coda

I am following the steps in the README.md but when I enter the following command:

```
python setup.py install
```

I receive the following error:

> running install                                                                                                                                                                       /home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.                                                                                                                                                     warnings.warn(                                                                                                                                                                      /home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.                                                                                                                                          warnings.warn(                                                                                                                                                                      running bdist_egg                                                                                                                                                                     running egg_info                                                                                                                                                                      writing src/py_coda.egg-info/PKG-INFO                                                                                                                                                 Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                      File "/mnt/c/Users/Owner/Desktop/Stage_2022/BH_M-sigma_compilation/py-coda/setup.py", line 5, in                                                                                setup(name='py-coda',                                                                                                                                                               File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup                                                         return run_commands(dist)                                                                                                                                                           File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands                                                  dist.run_commands()                                                                                                                                                                 File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands                                                  self.run_command(cmd)                                                                                                                                                               File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command                                                             super().run_command(command)                                                                                                                                                        File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command                                                   cmd_obj.run()                                                                                                                                                                       File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 74, in run                                                            self.do_egg_install()                                                                                                                                                               File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 123, in do_egg_install                                                self.run_command('bdist_egg')                                                                                                                                                       File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command                                                    self.distribution.run_command(command)                                                                                                                                              File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command                                                             super().run_command(command)                                                                                                                                                        File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command                                                   cmd_obj.run()                                                                                                                                                                       File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 156, in run                                                         self.run_command("egg_info")                                                                                                                                                        File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command                                                    self.distribution.run_command(command)                                                                                                                                              File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command                                                             super().run_command(command)                                                                                                                                                        File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command                                                   cmd_obj.run()                                                                                                                                                                       File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 291, in run                                                          writer(self, ep.name, os.path.join(self.egg_info, ep.name))                                                                                                                         File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 655, in write_pkg_info                                               metadata.write_pkg_info(cmd.egg_info)                                                                                                                                               File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 1118, in write_pkg_info                                               self.write_pkg_file(pkg_info)                                                                                                                                                       File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 193, in write_pkg_file                                                           license = rfc822_escape(self.get_license())                                                                                                                                         File "/home/osgrinds/mnt/c/Users/Owner/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/util.py", line 494, in rfc822_escape                                                 lines = header.split('\n')                                                                                                                                                        AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

I'm not sure what is causing this or how to solve it.

Comment: Have you cloned the repo first?

Comment: @mad_ yes I did. I followed the steps on the github

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing from the source(git) by

`pip install git+https://github.com/surhudm/py-coda`

Comment: When I try "pip install git+https://github.com/surhudm/py-coda" i get the following error: >ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: what does the full log say?